# Is there an easier way to validate my form in jquery rather than what I have??

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, dom

I am trying to create form validation using jquery. First, the code doesn't work for me and secondly I am hoping there is an easier way to use jquery to validate my form using reg ex patterns. I don't know if I am using jquery corectly and I would like to avoid using any plugins.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

        var pattern = /^\w+@[a-zA-Z_]+?\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$/;
        var pattern1 = /^\(?(\d{3})\)?[- ]?(\d{3})[- ]?(\d{4})$/; 
        var pattern2 = /[a-zA-Z]*( [a-zA-Z]*)?/;

   $('#submit').on('click', function() {
      var valid = true,
      errorMessage = "",


if ($('#role').val() == '') {
    errorMessage  = "please choose a role \n";
    valid = false;
}enter code here

if ($('#state').val() == '') {
    errorMessage  = "please choose a state \n";
    valid = false;
}

if ($('#major').val() == '') {
    errorMessage  = "please provide a major \n";
    valid = false;
}

if ($('#degree').val() == '') {
    errorMessage  = "please provide a degree \n";
    valid = false;
}

if ($('#location').val() == '') {
    errorMessage  = "please choose a location \n";
    valid = false;
}

if ($('#gradyear').val() == '') {
    errorMessage  = "please provide a graduation year \n";
    valid = false;
}

if ($('#dept').val() == '') {
    errorMessage  = "please provide your department \n";
    valid = false;
}

if ($('#campadd').val() == '') {
    errorMessage += "please enter your address\n";
     valid = false;
} 

if($('#email').val() !== ""){
        if(!pattern.test('#email'.val())){
            errorMessage += "email invalid!\n";                
            valid  = false;
        }
if($('#telephone').val() !== ""){
        if(!pattern1.test('#telephone'.val())){
            errorMessage += "telephone number invalid!\n";                
            valid  = false;
        }
    }}

if( !valid && errorMessage.length > 0){
    alert(errorMessage);
}
```

Comment: look at this http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation

Comment: Here is a concise example of how to use the JQuery Validate plugin: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/213138/An-Example-to-Use-jQuery-Validation-Plugin

Comment: Use a loop over a datastructure with ids, validation functions (you can use the same function multiple times), and messages.

Comment: There are some glaring issues with this code that may be preventing it from running as you expect, such as the text `enter code here` following the bracket on the first `if` statement. Also, the 3rd `if` from the end is missing a closing bracket.

Comment: u can use "blur" functions instead of all the if loops and also use some jquery validation plugin -- will make it easy!!

Answer (score 0):

First, the code formatting in your post is a bit off, which makes it somewhat difficult to read.  What exactly do you mean when you say it "doesn't work"?

My best guess is that you mean the form still submits, even after the errorMessage alert box appears.  If this is the case, that is probably because you are not canceling the submit event.

Change your code like this:

```
// submit instead of click event, give a name to the event argument
$('#submit').on('submit', function(e) {
//...

if( !valid && errorMessage.length > 0){
    e.preventDefault(); // prevents the form submission
    alert(errorMessage);
}
```